# Phpmyadmin(how to delete it which is shown in picture?)

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

[as i was managing the database some of them were junk and i want to delete  the folder of that database too how to do it with step by step?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/237a6.png)

so here in this picture you can see the red sign of folder "login test" how to delete it?

Answer (score 0):

Run a sql query in your phpmyadmin.

```
DROP DATABASE logintest;
```